# Can you water down wet food to trick a cat to drink more food?

Tags: cats, diet, safety, senior-pet

I had a 15 year old Maine Coon with severe kidney problems. With my current cat, who is a domestic short hair of seven years, I don't want him to suffer kidney problems when he is older. However, he rarely drinks water.

Can I water down the wet food to trick him into consuming a little more water? If I can, what is the limits of it?

Thanks.